# Deviation due to conditioning

Tags: references, conditional-expectation, mse

Let $A$ and $B$ be random variables. Can we upper-bound the following expression?
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big[\Big(\mathbb{E}[A|B] - \mathbb{E}[A]\Big)^2\Big]
$$
The above looks classical research. However, I am not able to find any references. Is there any literature which deals with such expressions?

Comment: This is bounded by $var(A)$ since this is the variance of the conditional expectation.

Answer (score 3):

$E[E[A|B]]=E[A]$ and so the expression is simply the variance of $E[A|B]$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}(A) &= E[\mathrm{Var}(A|B)] + \mathrm{Var}(E[A|B])\\
\mathrm{Var}(E[A|B]) &= \mathrm{Var}(A) -E[\mathrm{Var}(A|B)]\\
\implies \mathrm{Var}(E[A|B]) &\leq \mathrm{Var}(A)
\end{align*}